# Formato desconhecido de data no Oracle

Tags: oracle, data, pl-sql, formatação

Bom dia. 
Tenho que acessar os dados em um banco Oracle, onde um campo descrito como "data de validação" está com os seguintes dados:

```
DtValid
-------
115365
115364
115363
115362
115361
```

Alguém sabe que tipo de data é essa? Que formato é esse utilizado?
Obrigado.

Comment: O tipo da coluna é Date? Já vi casos em alguns sistemas que por questões de compatibilidade com outros softwares legados, utilizavam colunas de outros tipos para salvar dado ... pessoalmente eu considero uma péssima pratica, mas é possível. Caso seja um date, outra possibilidade é verificar o NLS_DATE_FORMAT da sessão.

Comment: Um palpite seria dias ocorridos desde uma determinada data (bem antiga talvez) na realidade o DATE é gravado como segundos decorridos desde uma determinada data (1 de janeiro de 4712 AC creio)

Comment: O pior é que o campo no banco é um numérico de 6 posições.